# Mule http listener and log4j2 config with domain

Tags: mule

I am able to configure Mule log4j2.xml file and get the logs in local and server. 
But when I make project as domain project([shared resource](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/shared-resources)) and deploy application in Mule server, it doesn't create logger folder and creates the logs.

Another issue is when I try to invoke http url, it says resource not found. http://serverhost:8010/domain/test

Response in browser:

> Resource not found.

Same is working fine in Anypoint studio, problem occurs only in server.

domain project: test-domain
mule-domain-config.xml: having http listener as:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="${http.host}" port="8010" basePath="domain" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${MULE_HOME}/conf/product/common-app.properties"/>
```

Test project:

```
<flow name="testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="INFO---Logger--" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">${env:MULE_HOME}/logs/test-domain</Property>
        <Property name="log-name">mylog</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
.....
```

local log file in Studio:

[image]

Without domain project, everything is working fine.

Mule version: 3.7